# changing plot manually

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, mouseevent

I am trying to implement things from this link-

http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/05/27/advanced-matlab-capture-mouse-movement/

in a bit more complex gui.. I have a curve plotted, and using a peakfinder function I find all the maxima in the plot,and mark them with an X (using another plot function) but then I want the user to have the ability to correct the location of the maxima if they are wrong, or to erase some X if they are unnecessary.

I can’t understand what should I change or add to make it work to drag only a certain X each step.

in this code it isn't a gui but I still have the same problem

my code-

```
function main

global data_file

x=0:0.1:100
data_file=sin(x)*5+(rand(100*10+1,1)’-0.5)

starting_sample= 1;
sampling_rate=1;

len = length(data_file);

f = figure('NumberTitle','off','color','w','Menubar','none');

[picks1,locs1] = findpeaks(data_file(starting_sample:sampling_rate:len),'MINPEAKDISTANCE',10);
a = axes('xlim',[0 100], 'ylim',[-5 5]);

plot( 1:sampling_rate:len, data_file( starting_sample:sampling_rate:len ) );
hold on
p=plot(locs1,picks1,'x','linewidth',2,'color','r','ButtonDownFcn',@start_drag1);
hold off

set(f,'WindowButtonUpFcn',@stop_drag1)

    function start_drag1(varargin)
        set(f,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@draging)
    end

    function draging(varargin)
        pt= get(a,'currentpoint')
        set(p,'XData',pt(1)*[1 1])
    end

    function stop_drag1(varargin)
        set(f,'WindowButtonMotionFcn','')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the minimum/maximum step size that you can drag then you need to edit your `draging` function to incrementally update `XData` after some dragging threshold has been crossed.

Something like this might work

```
function draging(varargin)

   dragDist = 1;
   pt = get(a,'currentpoint')
   curX = get(p,'XData')

   if ( curX(1) - pt(1) > dragDist) %drag to the left
      set(p,'XData',curX - dragDist)
   elseif (pt(1) - curX(1) > dragDist) % drag to the right
      set(p, 'XData', curX + dragDist)
   end

end
```

Comment: there are two things missing in yout answer-                                        1. when it drags - it drags all the Xes , and i want it to drag only one and leave the others in their place..                                   2. it changes only to the sides and not to up\down.                                 can you add those things?

Comment: @user1742463 what is missing?